# Cannot solve Multiple operations with path 'Entry' and method 'GET' with Attribute routing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, url-routing

I am hosting my own WebApi, as can be seen below:  This is run as a Windows service, so can be started and stopped.

I am using Swagger/Swashbuckle to test my api.

I have the following code.

```
public class ApiShell : IApiShell
    {
        IDisposable _webApp;

        public void Start()
        {
            _webApp = WebApp.Start<Startup>("http://localhost:9090");
            Console.WriteLine($"Web server running at 'http://localhost:9090'");
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _webApp.Dispose();
        }

        internal class Startup
        {
            //Configure Web API for Self-Host
            public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
            {
                var config = new HttpConfiguration();
                config.EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.SingleApiVersion("1", "Api");
                    c.PrettyPrint();
                }).EnableSwaggerUi(c => c.EnableDiscoveryUrlSelector());

                var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(IoC.Container);
                config.DependencyResolver = resolver;

                config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("DefaultApi", "{controller}/{id}", new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

                config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes(); //Swagger does not load when I have the following uncommented
                config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);

                app.UseWebApi(config);

                GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is, when I don't add `config.MapHttpAttributeroutes`, I get the following error:

> Multiple operations with path 'Entry' and method 'GET'

When I do add `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes` to try and solve this, I get the following error:

> The object has not yet been initialized. Ensure that HttpConfiguration.EnsureInitialized() is called in the application's startup code after all other initialization code

I have added `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnsureInitialized();`, but this does not help.

Here is my routes:

```
[RoutePrefix("api")]
    public class EntryController : ApiController
    {
        private IActorSystemShell _actorSystem;

        public EntryController(IActorSystemShell actorSystem)
        {
            _actorSystem = actorSystem;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<dynamic> AddPhoneBook([FromBody] Entry entry)
        {
            ...
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<dynamic> GetEntries()
        {
            ...
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("id/{id}")]
        public async Task<dynamic> GetEntryById(int id)
        {
            ...
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("text/{searchText}/SearchAll")]
        public async Task<dynamic> SearchEntries(string searchText)
        {
            ...
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("book/{bookId}/{searchText}")]
        public async Task<dynamic> SearchInPhoneBook(int bookId, string searchText)
        {
            ...
        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you please mark an answer as accepted or give more information

Comment: I will post my answer here a little later.

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to a Swagger limitation as discussed [here](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/142) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601890/not-supported-by-swagger-2-0-multiple-operations-with-path). You could try giving all you HttpGet calls a specific name with:

> [SwaggerOperation("GETOPERATION")]

This could also be because not all your actions have route attributes

Comment: Yes my best bet is on Routing or SwaggerOperation declaration